# What happen if the glide slope beacon removed for maintenance?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-performance, airline-operations

it about aircraft navigation system (ILS), when the aircraft about to landing but unfortunately the glideslope beacon being removed.

Comment: *The aircraft is about to land but unfortunately the glideslope beacon is removed* [Just kidding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_rWja1Xiu8)!

Answer (score 2):

Instrument Landing Systems routinely undergo maintenance and it is common to have the Glide Path unserviceable while the Localizer is still serviceable.

An aircraft can still make an approach and land, but the approach is now classified as a Localizer approach. The weather limit minimums are increased from the usual 200’ above ground, to approximately 300-500’ above ground. (depends on local geography)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little ambiguous. This is assuming you can get clearance for the approach and that it has not been NOTAMed as completely out of service.

If you are asking about the procedure if the glideslope vertical guidance transmitter is inoperative, in most cases you treat the approach as a LOC localizer or LNAV only approach. You would use the LOC/LNAV only procedures, criteria, step-downs, and minimums. You would have an MDA(H) (Minimum Descent Altitude or Height) instead of a DA(H) (Decision Altitude or Height).

If you are asking about the procedure if the marker beacon(s) is/are inoperative, you would use one of the alternate means of identifying the Final Approach Fix. This could be done utilizing DME or GPS. In some cases, it is marked on the Instrument Approach Procedure chart as an intersection of a VOR Radial. Otherwise, you would follow the glideslope vertical guidance all the way down to the DA(H). Make note that the DA(H)/MDA(H) may be adjusted if you can not identify certain points, or if the altitude can not be verified due to unavailable local altimeter readings.

Always check the notes for special instructions, adjustments, or requirements like Radar Services Required or what to do when a fix can not be identified.